# Как узнать время Date в миллисекундах до конца дня?

Tags: java, дата

Есть некая дата, которую нужно взять в милисекундах. Например,

```
date.getTime();
```

Как узнать время в миллисекундах до конца этого дня? Допустим, у нас `date = 2017-10-27T10:00.000`, а надо получить для `2017-10-27:23.59.999`

Comment: Вам интервал нужен от текущего времени до конца дня? Или вам нужно получить значение времени конца дня в миллисекундах?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если используется Java8, то получить интервал до конца дня достаточно просто, нужно воспользоваться `ChronoUnit`:

```
LocalTime current = LocalTime.now()
long millis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(current, LocalTime.MAX)
```

Если у вас уже есть какая-то дата класса `Date` для которой нужно посчитать интервал, можно привести её к LocalTime и точно так же посчитать:

```
Date date = new Date();
LocalTime current = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
long millis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(current, LocalTime.MAX)
```

Comment: Java 8. Очень не хватает знаний в ней.. Посоветуйте пожалуйста книги/сайты где собрана информация только о 8? И только вся

Comment: К сожалению не могу подсказать, потому что не знаю таких книг

Comment: Вот за это и люблю SO - всегда можно что-то новое узнать :)

Answer (score 3):

Это легко сделать через календарь

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long beforeMidnight = (c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Здесь мы прибавляем к дню единицу, тем самым получаем завтрашний день. Затем сбрасываем часы, минуты, секунды и миллисекунды на 0, чтобы получить 00:00.

Затем берём время в миллисекундах из нашего календаря и отнимаем от него системное время в миллисекундах. Получаем количество миллисекунд до полночи!

P. S Если вам нужно именно 23:59:999, то просто отнимите единицу :D

Answer (score 2):

До конца дня - нужно получить время в миллисекундах конца дня. Т.е. например можно воспользоваться классом java.util.Date. Если создать объект с пустым конструктором то вы получите объект с данными о текущем времени, а важнее с текущей датой. Можно в ручную методами setHour и setMinute изменить время на конец дня. Т.е. на 23 и 59. Потом через метод getTime получаем время конца дня в миллисекундах. Из этого значения вычитаем то, от которого хотим получить разницу. В итоге имеем разницу в миллисекундах. Делим на 1000 и получаем разницу в секундах. Делим секунды на 60 и получаем разницу в минутах. Так далее можно посчитать разницу вплоть до количества лет с точностью до миллисекунд.

Comment: Количество лет до конца дня? :)

Comment: @Flippy сформулировал криво. Я хотел сказать, что такой метод позволяет найти разницу во времени между событиями вне зависимости от того в один день произошли эти события или нет. Подскажете как лучше выразиться?